# Get the Text box and drop down value inside a Table which is created dynamically using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Please help ,i am new to jquery . Have 3 tables which will fill the textboxes and  drop down "select" dynamically

```
<table class="primaGridViewSmall" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="95%"
    id="shareAddUserMember" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" align="left">
</table>

<table class="primaGridViewSmall" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="95%"
    id="shareAddUserMemberA" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" align="left">
</table>

<table class="primaGridViewSmall" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="95%"
    id="shareAddUserMemberB" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" align="left">
</table>
```

The table can have so many text boxs and "select" drop down  that added dynamically by clicking "add more".
Actually i want to implement some thing like this from the textbox and select in that table

```
var array = [];
var j = 0;
$('#shareAddUserMember tr').each(function () {
    var memberID = ?  // Dynamic_textbox_value;
    var privilage = ? // Dynamic_drop_down_selected value ie type <select>
    if (memberID != "") {
        array[j] = memberID + ":" + privilage;
        j++;
    }
});
```

I have tried this to get the value of textbox ,i need select also

```
$('#shareAddUserMember tr').each(function () {
    $('input[type=text]').each(function (i, item) {
    var grade = $(item).val();
        alert(grade);
    });
});
```

But above code  will fetch all the input types in the page .I have more than one table .I need to fetch value in text boxes which is created dynamically(id is dynamically generated) inside the table shareAddUserMember  .

I need the value of textbox only inside the table having  id ="shareAddUserMember " not shareAddUserMemberA or shareAddUserMemberB.

```
$('#shareAddUserMember tr').each(function () {
     // ---what to write here  to fetch the textbox and drop down selected values-----------
});
```

Actually i want to implement some thing like this from the textbox and input type select  in that table

```
var array = [];
var j = 0;
$('#shareAddUserMember tr').each(function () {
    var memberID = ?  // Dynamic_textbox_value;
    var privilage = ? // Dynamic_drop_down_selected value ie type <select>
    if (memberID != "") {
        array[j] = memberID + ":" + privilage;
        j++;
    }
});
```

Inside the tr there is drop down and select sample DOM

```
<table class="primaGridViewSmall" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="95%"
    id="shareAddUserMember" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" align="left">
  <tr id="EmailIDUserRow1">
    <td style="text-align: center; width: 3%;">
      <input type="hidden" id="EmailUserMemberID1" name="EmailUserMemberID1" />
    </td>
    <td align="left">
      <select style="width: 150px" name="select1" id="select1">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Full Access </option>
        <option value="0">View Only</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: just put assign `ID` to your input and then you can get value from one text box OR if your textbox is inside the table then you can have something like this: `$('#shareAddUserMember tr input[type=text]').each(function (i, item){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over each tr element inside `#shareAddUserMember`:

```
$("#shareAddUserMember tr").each(function() {
  // `this` refers to the current tr element

  // Get the input box and select that are inside the current tr element using
  // $(this).find()
  var memberID = $(this).find("input:text").val();
  var privilege = $(this).find("select").val();

  if (memberID !== "") {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Hope that helps or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: i also want the drop down selected value (<select>) Actually i want to implement something like this
 $('#shareAddUserMember tr').each(function () {
            var memberID = textbox value;
            var privilage = drop down selected value 
            if (memberID != "") {
                array[j] = memberID + ":" + privilage;
                j++;
            }
            
        });

Comment: It would help a lot if you update your question with the pseudocode since comments don't support code formatting. Aside from that, is there a 1-to-1 mapping between drop downs and input boxes? It would also be helpful to see some sample HTML.

Comment: I have updated the Question ,thanks There is no 1to1 mapping ,just a text box and input type select drop down ,just user select from the drop down and enter some comment in the text box  from the UI .

Comment: No in tr both text box and select,updated the question ,check last para :(

Comment: @avengerr Edited to reflect your DOM structure. I would point you to the jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/) for more information about how each() and find() work, as well as other methods for iterating/filtering DOM elements.

Comment: If the textbox  input type is hidden then i used  var memberID = $(this).find("input:hidden").val();Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#shareAddUserMember tr input[type=text]').each(function () {            
     // do some of your magic in here :)
});
```

Since you have updated your answer you can try something like this (I didn't test this code)

```
$('#shareAddUserMember').each(function () {            
        var memberID = $('#shareAddUserMember tr input[type=text]').val();
        var privilage = $("#shareAddUserMember tr select option:selected").text();
        if (memberID != "") {
            array[j] = memberID + ":" + privilage;
            j++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ya great that work,I also  want to get the selected value of type "select" ie,drop down inside that table in one each statement ,then ?
I want to implement some ting like this
$('#shareAddUserMember tr').each(function () {
            var memberID = textbox value;
            var privilage = drop down selected value 
            if (memberID != "") {
                array[j] = memberID + ":" + privilage;
                j++;
            }
            
        });

Comment: not working ,it loops only one time and only first text box value is getting and it appending all the drop down values into privilage.I want one by one and store it into array :(